# using maps to count large data

Tags: c++, dictionary

I cannot get this to process a large file. I changed from using arrays to maps because this might help. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
map<char,int> freq;
size_t size = 0;
for (char c; cin.get(c); size++){
   if (isalpha(c))
      freq[tolower(c)]++;
      }
cout << "char" << freq['a'] << endl;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm getting a count of each lower case letter in my file.

Comment: @harman2012: From the code, you seem to be counting all letters, upper or lower case.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Sample input/output? It looks like you probably have a bug printing

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `char` may be signed in which case you cannot pass a `char` directly to any of the `<cctype>` functions: You'll need to cast it to `unsigned char` first. For example, trying to process my name on a system set to use ISO Latin-1 encoding will result in undefined behavior on systems where `char` is signed.

Comment: I haven't had issue with input, I think. I have processed a smaller file.

Answer (score 2):

Since `char` by the standard is only eight bits, using the whole map for it is rather wasteful. Declare an array of 256 `int`s, make your `char` into an `unsigned`, and count the frequency in the fastest way imaginable:

```
int freq[256];
size_t size = 0;
// Count without any checks or conditions
for (char c ; cin.get(c) ; size++) {
    freq[(unsigned char)c]++;
}
// Go through the lowercase letters, and add upper frequencies to them
for (int i = 'a' ; i <= 'z' ; i++) {
    freq[i] += freq[toupper(i)];
    cout << (char)i << " --> " << freq[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: I changed `freq[tolower(i)]` but yeah after execution, there's no output.

Comment: @harman2012 That is very strange: you should get 26 lines of output no matter what, even if all counts are zero. How do you pass the input to your program? Do you use file redirect? Are you sure that you are terminating your program correctly?

Comment: I'm using a.out file, `ifstream cin(argv[1])`.

Comment: Try adding some debug output. Also try running this on a tiny file (say, with the `quick brown fox ...` string, where frequencies are trivial to calculate manually).

Comment: Yes, I've tried a file having just one sentence and then have to ^Z to exit. This works for you?

Comment: @harman2012 Wait, you said that you are reading from a file. Why do you need a Ctrl-Z then? The loop is supposed to end once the reading is over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21235/discussion-between-harman2012-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: @harman2012 I just ran this locally on OS X, the code worked perfectly without Ctrl-Z